# Marking mail as spam in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

Is there an easy way to flag mail as spam within Thunderbird? I get heaps of spam and having to go deep within the menu to create custom rules and name them different things every time I want to block a string of messages is quite annoying. Gmail has a quick button, so does Thunderbird?

Answer (score 2):

There's a flame icon in the list of mails received. Click on the small round button in that flame column, and it will mark it as junk/spam.
[image]

Comment: I've done that before but I don't know if it actually does anything? Do you know what it does? Will it prevent me from getting mail like that in the future?

Comment: It adds the post to a junk filter log, which I presume "learns" what is spam and what isn't. It isn't clearly told what it does: https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/thunderbird-and-junk-spam-messages (search for: "Training the junk filter")

Comment: Ok, I had to set another filter to do something with the spam, otherwise all it does it mark it as junk and remains going to your inbox. I just redirect it to spam folder now.